# Material Design Bootstrap (MDBReact) is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-design, mdbreact

[image]

Getting following error on using mdbreact components,

> ←→1 of 2 errors on the page Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only
> be called inside of the body of a function component. This could
> happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "mdbreact": "^4.27.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

I have added following index.js

```
   import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'; 
    import 'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import 'mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css';
```

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import CardExample from './ReviewCard'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CardExample />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ReviewCard.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { MDBBtn, MDBCard, MDBCardBody, MDBCardImage, MDBCardTitle, MDBCardText, MDBCol } from 'mdbreact';

const CardExample = () => {
  return (
    <MDBCol>
      <MDBCard style={{ width: "22rem" }}>
        <MDBCardImage className="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" waves />
        <MDBCardBody>
          <MDBCardTitle>Card title</MDBCardTitle>
          <MDBCardText>
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make
            up the bulk of the card&apos;s content.
          </MDBCardText>
          <MDBBtn href="#">MDBBtn</MDBBtn>
        </MDBCardBody>
      </MDBCard>
    </MDBCol>
  )
}

export default CardExample;
```

Comment: add some code   of the error

Comment: @krimo https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/components/cards/ just used simple card. I have used MDBreact earlier as well. It used to work.

Comment: try to verfiy to import hooks in your component

Comment: Can you add your complete file from where this error coming?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma, please find the comment in below answer

Comment: @AnkitaJaiswal what is the code for `ReviewCard`?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma, refresh the page, i have added all the required code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they are not migrated to latest `react ^17`. Try reducing react version to `16.*`. It works like charm.

Here is `package.json` that I used:

```
"dependencies": {
    "mdbreact": "4.27.0",
    "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
```

Here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mdbreact-02pbr) you can check

Comment: yeah...issue  lies in version only.

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "mdbreact": "4.27.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
}
this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I don't think because of MDBReact. Maybe you can move the Hooks into main default function.

Also if you can share your code, we can help easier.

Comment: import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import CardExample from './ReviewCard'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CardExample />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Comment: CardExample is the first example code in the link shared in https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/components/cards/

Answer (score 0):

You have to install latest mdb npm package using command npm i mdb-react-ui-kit. It will work with React 17. You don't need to downgrade your react version

add below line in index.js
import 'mdb-react-ui-kit/dist/css/mdb.min.css'

add below line in index.html for fontawesome